# Should remoting tag be renamed to powershell-remoting?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I found a tag called [remoting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remoting) which seems to uniformly refer to questions about [PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585(v=vs.85).aspx). Therefore, I suggest changing the [remoting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remoting) tag to be named [powershell-remoting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell-remoting). Why?

- When somebody is asking a question, they are very likely to add "powershell" as a tag. By adding powershell as a prefix to the "remoting" tag, it becomes more discoverable thanks to the auto-completion assistant.
- The most common related tags are currently:

  - powershell x 14
  - winrm x 5
  - windows x 3
  - a bunch of other single-use tags that are all Windows-related technology
- Some precedent shown in other tags to have a topic prefix

  - http-headers
  - vmware-vcenter
  - email-bounces
  - windows-authentication
  - cisco-vpn

Answer (score 8):

I don't see why not.  [remoting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remoting) alone doesn't seem to have a great deal of meaning alone.